# getting weird log message on console(AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, size-classes

Hiii Guys,

I have a view with 600*450 size, now i put a collection view in a view with 600*430 size. when i am running application i am getting this weird message on console

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285960 V:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7fb133860800]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x60000019df60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285a50 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fb133860800]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x60000019df60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285dc0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b5b60]-(0)-[UIView:0x60000019dc20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285e10 UIView:0x60000019dc20.height == 0.25*UIView:0x60000019db50.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002860e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b5b60]-(0)-[UIView:0x60800019d5a0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286180 UIView:0x60000019df60.bottom == UIView:0x60000019ddc0.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286220 UIView:0x60000019df60.top == UIView:0x60800019d5a0.top>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286540 UIView:0x60000019dcf0.height == 0.25*UIView:0x60000019db50.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000286590 V:[UIView:0x60000019dc20]-(0)-[UIView:0x60000019dcf0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002867c0 UIView:0x60000019ddc0.height == 0.25*UIView:0x60000019db50.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002868b0 V:[UIView:0x60000019dcf0]-(0)-[UIView:0x60000019ddc0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000288d40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x60000019db50(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000285a50 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fb133860800]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x60000019df60 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

i don't know what to do.

[image]

I have applied this 4 constraints to UICollectionView.

Comment: Have you tried adding a width/height constraint? That may solve your problem.

Comment: i have applied but not working @Rafal

Comment: are you adding the collection view directly to controller or inside any other view and if you are adding with other views then make sure the constraints are applied correctly for that view also.

Comment: your error indicates that somewhere you are using proportional height constraint and that caused this log.

Comment: Try clicking "resolve Auto Layout issues" in the interface builder, and then selecting "update constraints" or "add missing constraints". This might give you a hint as to where is the problem.

Comment: but interface builder not showing any auto layout isssues

Answer (score 0):

This occur because few constraint you have added is not required so it is better to select the view and then after Choose Reset to suggested constraint .

[image]

and if after this if constraint not up to mark then better to look for each control constraint and check which constraint showing mark (yellow)and try to remove manually and then add.

Hope it helps.